# Is there an interactive notebook tool for R as iPython Notebook?

Tags: r

I've been using RStudio and I like it, but for the type of work I do a Notebook environment (like iPython Notebook) is more useful than an IDE. Is there an iPython Notebook equivalent for R?

Comment: I haven't encountered such a tool.  However, I thought iPython actually has some capabilities of interfacing with R.  Additionally, have you tried the nifty "Compile Notebook" button in RStudio (requires the knitr package FYI)?  I tried iPython briefly, but I just couldn't get used to the notebook style.  What work do you do that lends itself so well to that?

Comment: The packlage linked from the answer unfortunately doesn't provide an interactive notebook interface.  It's just some sort of report generator: makes R code and results embeddable in in a document.  This is a common misconception about what a notebook interface is, mostly propagated by people who have never worked with real notebooks, like the ones used by Mathematica and IPython.  Here's a real notebook interface for R: https://github.com/takluyver/IRkernel

Comment: Yes, iPython has evolved into the [Jupyter Project](http://jupyter.org/), which fully supports interactive iPython-style notebooks for Python, R and Julia. There is a test-drive server here: https://tmpnb.org

Answer (score 3):

There is a [R Notebook with rCharts](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-creates-d3javascript-charts-in-ipython-style-notebook/) which embed D3/JavaScript in R Notebook using rCharts and Shiny.  rCharts allows you to create charts using an iPython-like interface.  In the link you will see a video that shows how it works.